# Change app name

Tags: android

note: I read the former post about changing app name. The label of my app should be correct, still it is not.

I have an android app that I made.
It consists of different activities.
But when I downloaded my app, it is called "Sign in". This should not be the case, I want it to be called something else. How can I achieve this?

Here is my manifest file:

```
....
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my strings file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Exigentia</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="EmergencyButton">EmergencyButton</string>
    <string name="title_activity_login">Sign in</string>

    <!-- Strings related to login -->
    <string name="prompt_email">Email</string>
    <string name="prompt_password">Password (optional)</string>
    <string name="action_sign_in">Sign in or register</string>
    <string name="action_sign_in_short">Sign in</string>
    <string name="error_invalid_email">This email address is invalid</string>
    <string name="error_invalid_password">This password is too short</string>
    <string name="error_incorrect_password">This password is incorrect</string>
    <string name="error_field_required">This field is required</string>
    <string name="permission_rationale">"Contacts permissions are needed for providing email
        completions."
    </string>
</resources>
```

So why does my app display "Sign in" as its name, and not Exigentia?

Note: this is before I click my app and launch it. Once it is launched, the sign in should be there in the top

Answer (score 1):

According to the App Manifest's [`<activity> label`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#label) attribute:

> A user-readable label for the activity. The label is displayed on-screen when the activity must be represented to the user. It's often displayed along with the activity icon.
>
> If this attribute is not set, the label set for the application as a whole is used instead (see the <application> element's label attribute).

An application can have multiple entry points represented by multiple activites. For example, you want to create an application that has both a teacher and a student entry points on the user's phone without requiring them to install multiple apps. This also means that you can assign different labels to the activites, like *Teacher* and *Student*, respectively.

Basically, when you create an app with a single main Activity, you just place the app name on the <application> tag and the icon in the main menu will have that label. Obviously for multiple Activity entry points this would not be great, so you have the option to override it one-by-one.

I think you want to achieve that the label be displayed on the app bar (action bar, toolbar, you name it). This should be done by either putting the label onto the app bar in the layout XML or using code, such as `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_activity_login);`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have translations in your app? This could be the problem because android displays the local strings if exists. If you have translations, make sure you have changed the app_name string in all strings.xml files. Guaranteed way to make sure if you have translations is that go to your project directory and see if there are multiple "values" folders under "...\app\src\main\res" like "values-en", "values-de" etc.

Answer (score 0):

No need to put label in all activity Tags. Try below one:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```